# Array not displaying properly when passed to a function as pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Given below is my `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    int N = 4;
    int A[N][N] = {
        {1 , 0 , 0 , 0},
        {1 , 1 , 0 , 1},
        {0 , 1 , 0 , 0},
        {1 , 1 , 1 , 1}
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    printSolution(N , *A);
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here I had declared a 4x4 array with values. Given below is printSolution where I am passing a pointer to the array inside it.

```
void printSolution(int N , int *sol)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            cout << *((sol + i) + j) << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Given below is the output:

```
1 0 0 0
1 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1

1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0
```

As it is visible in the output, the for loop inside the main function printed the array correctly, whereas the `printSolution()` function could not print it properly. Why is that so?

Comment: The question aside, this is C++ -- you should be using `<array>` or `<vector>`.

Comment: I have been told to use pointers, that's why

Comment: Ah. Another instructor teaching C first... [he shouldn't be doing that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk&t=124s)...

Comment: @Ali , operator to '*' must be a pointer

Comment: `int A[N][N]` is not a valid declaration since `N` is not a constant expression. Many compilers allow it anyway as an unofficial extension called "variable length arrays", but those can bite you in tricky ways. Use `constexpr int N = 4;` (or `const int N = 4;`) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*((sol + i) + j)
```

Say, for i = 2 and j = 2 this is merely `*(sol + 4)`, the element in row 1 column 0 (exactly what is printed.)

You probably want `*((sol + i * N) + j)`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be an undefined behaviour? `sol` is a pointer to {1 , 0 , 0 , 0}, accessing other elements beyond this array is UB, no?

Comment: @KillzoneKid "A declaration of the form T a[N];, declares a as an array object that consists of N contiguously allocated objects of type T." Op passes `*A` as function's argument which is the first row of the array, other rows following contiguously.

Comment: @bipll the size `N` of the array `sol` points to is `4`, it is not pointing to 1D array of `int` the size of `N*4`

Comment: @KillzoneKid: indeed, pedantically `sol[4]` (`A[0][4]`) is UB. In practice, we read `A[1][0]`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Would this be a better example of this kind of UB? https://ideone.com/dErrGU

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Same for me, just that `sol + 4` is correct (as one beyond the array the `end`) whereas `sol + 6` is already UB (without need to deference it)